# How to represent fork() && fork() in workflow tree?

Tags: c, multithreading, tree, fork

In C, the fork() function will return a non zero value for the parent process and zero for the child process.

When working with logical expression such as && or ||, it confused me when trying to know how those codes work. How do I show them in tree by graph theory? How the codes were executed?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 
int main() 
{ 
   fork(); 
   fork() && fork(); // or fork() || fork() 

   printf("forked\n"); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: As for your problem please think about the [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) used by the logical operator `&&` and `||`, and a little bit more what [`fork`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fork.html) returns, and what "false" and "true" values there are.

Comment: `fork() && fork()`: Consider that `&&` is short-circuit. The process which executes this, calls both. Its first child process (which receives 0 for the first) doesn't execute the second. (First and second child processes continue with `printf()`.)

Comment: `fork()` can also return -1 (nonzero) on an error, so be sure to consider that as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both logical **AND** (`&&`) and logical **OR** (`||`) operator employs short-circuiting behavior.

`expr1 && expr2`: `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `0` (**false**).
`expr1 || expr2`: `expr2` is not evaluated if `expr1` is logical `1` (**true**).

With logical short-circuiting, the second operand, `expr2`, is *evaluated* only when the result is not fully determined by the first operand, `expr1`.

Assuming all the `fork()` calls in parent as well as child process are result in success, the tree of forked processes will be like this:

```
 parent process
     |
     |
   fork()    // first fork
   -----     // below in the tree, RV is fork() returned value
     |
     |----child process [RV: 0]--
     |                          |
   [RV: child PID]              |
     |                          |
   fork() && fork()            fork() && fork()
   ------                      ------
     |                          |
     |                          |--child process [RV: 0]--
     |                          |                        |
     |                         [RV: X (child PID)]       |
     |                          |                      0 && fork()   
     |                          |                   // due to && short-circuiting behavior, 
     |                          |                   // fork() will not be called
     |                          |                        |
     |                          |                       Print "forked"
     |                          |                       Exit
     |                          |
     |                          |
     |                    X && fork()   // X is a non zero value and hence the fork() will be called
     |                         ------
     |                          |
     |                          |--child process [RV: 0]--
     |                          |                        |
     |                        [RV: child PID]            |
     |                          |                        |
     |                         Print "forked"           Print "forked"
     |                         Exit                     Exit
     |
     |--child process [RV: 0]--
     |                        |
   [RV: X (child PID)]        |
     |                      0 && fork()
     |                      // due to && short-circuiting behavior, fork() will not be called
     |                        |
     |                        |
     |                      Print "forked"
     |                      Exit
     |
X && fork()   // X is a non zero value and hence the fork() will be called
     ------
     |
     |--child process [RV: 0]--
     |                        |
   [RV: child PID]            |
     |                        |
     |                        |
   Print "forked"           Print "forked"
   Exit                     Exit
```

I hope this will help you in understanding the execution. Try yourself for `fork() || fork()` expression. Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 3):

## Short circuit evalutation

> For the built-in logical AND operator, the result is true if both
>   operands are true. Otherwise, the result is false. This operator is
>   short-circuiting: if the first operand is false, the second operand is
>   not evaluated

So for this line:

```
fork() && fork()
```

The first `fork` is evaluated `true` in the child and the child will fork one more (and the parent is done for this statement due to the short circuit).

The opposite happends with:

```
fork() || fork()
```

And the parent will fork one more.

### Equivalent code

An equivalent way of writing the same is with an `if` statement:

```
if (fork()){
  fork();
}
```

*and*

```
if (!fork()){
  fork();
}
```